# is there any way for Separating holidays from weekdays in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I live in Iran, and holidays in Iran are different from the calendar. I need to cut off the weekend from weekdays.
I have Iranian holidays on my calendar.
my table is something like that :

```
start_date           finish_date         datediff(day)
---------------------------------------------------
03/03/2018           03/09/2018          6
03/10/2018           03/21/2018          11
```

And I know Iranian holidays include these days:

```
03/05/2018
03/11/2018
03/19/2018
```

So I need to reduce Iranian holidays from any time interval. for-example , time 03/05/2018 is in the first interval and it should be reduced from this interval.
The point is that I can not join table of holiday and the Time interval tables Because they are on two different databases.

final table is something like that :

```
start_date           finish_date         datediff(day)   Difference_of_time_ 
                                                         except_the_holidays
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
03/03/2018           03/09/2018          6                       5
03/10/2018           03/21/2018          11                      9
```

Comment: a) The count of holidays within the interval is wrong. From 03rd to 09th there are7 days, not 6 (3,4,5,6,7,8,9). You have to add 1 to the difference. b) How do you get the additional holidays if you do not have any table?

Comment: Hello . This is just an example and the numbers are not real.
I have a table for all  holidays and also for time interval, but they come from two different systems and two different databases. time interval come from jira data base and holidays come from a  Login and exit system of Employees.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53677890/how-to-add-number-of-business-days-to-given-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dealt with this exact issue in my last two companies.  In each case, a solution that has worked very well is to maintain a work days calendar that contains all days: work days, weekends, holidays and classifies each.  It also has a running index to indicate a work days has elapsed or not.  Here is a sample:

```
cal_date   is_workday  day_type     workday_index   workday_index_back
  7/1/2018 0           WE                    4635                 4635
  7/2/2018 1           WD                    4636                 4635
  7/3/2018 1           WD                    4637                 4636
  7/4/2018 0           HD                    4637                 4637
  7/5/2018 1           WD                    4638                 4637
  7/6/2018 1           WD                    4639                 4638
  7/7/2018 0           WE                    4639                 4639
  7/8/2018 0           WE                    4639                 4639
  7/9/2018 1           WD                    4640                 4639
 7/10/2018 1           WD                    4641                 4640
 7/11/2018 1           WD                    4642                 4641
 7/12/2018 1           WD                    4643                 4642
 7/13/2018 1           WD                    4644                 4643
 7/14/2018 0           WE                    4644                 4644
 7/15/2018 0           WE                    4644                 4644
```

(July 4 is a holiday in the US).

The `workday_index` field increments every workday and does not on non-work days.  The table is pretty easy to build, as you can imagine, once you have your calendar of holidays defined.

The numbers themselves don't mean anything, per se -- they are just a mechanism to count the number of work days against the entire calendar.

From here, calculating the difference between to dates is as easy as:

```
select
  t.start_date, t.finish_date,
  t.finish_date - t.start_date as calendar_days,
  wd2.workday_index - wd1.workday_index as work_days
from
  table t
  join work_days wd1 on t.start_date = wd1.cal_date
  join work_days wd2 on t.finish_date = wd2.cal_date
```

You can also do things like calculate the number of work days away something is.  For example, if you have a customer need date and a lead-time (days to manufacture), then you can calculate the latest possible start date as follows:

```
select
  c.need_date, c.lead_time_days, 
  wd2.cal_date as earliest_possible_start_date
from
  customer_data c
  join util.work_days wd1 on c.need_date = wd1.cal_date
  join util.work_days wd2 on wd1.workday_index - c.lead_time_days = wd2.workday_index
```

As an added bonus, the table also works differently if you want to apply a roll-forward versus a roll-back rule -- that's why there are two workday indexes -- forward and backward.  This is applicable because how you handle a non-workday may be context sensitive.

For example, if a customer wants his product by Saturday -- then his need date is really Friday (roll back).  However, if you have a promised delivery from a vendor on Saturday, then the date needs to roll forward -- you don't really have it until Monday.